# Can adverbs modify prepositions afterwards?

Tags: adverbs

“Do you see why I feel this way?” “Oh yes, I'm with you completely.”

It's not "I'm completely with you."

If he's for helping the poor, I'm with him all the way!

It's not "I'm all the way with him."

https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/with

I think adverbs can modify prepositions afterwards.

Then, can I say "the car is out of gas completely" instead of "the car is completely out of gas"?

Comment: I wouldn't call **all the way** an adverb. The ultimate figurative meaning is "without reservation, fully committed" and the intermediate literal meaning is something like "(for) the entire journey".  We wouldn't say "I'm for the entire journey with him".

Comment: "All the way" is a noun phrase consisting of the noun phrase "the way" modified by the determinative "all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are correct. In those sentences, the *prepositional phrases*(not just the preposition) function as adjectives, and (some) adverbs can modify adjectives. Some more examples,and note use of comma:

- *The arrow is precisely in the center,* or the *The arrow is in the center, precisely,*

By putting the adverb at the end, and pausing before it, attention is drawn to the adverb, emphasizing it.

Comment: In both cases, the PPs are locative complements of the verb "be". In the first example "precisely" modifies the PP "in the centre". In the second, "precisely" is an adjunct.